# Is db.collection.insert() through pymongo secure?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I have MongoDB instance running on AWS EC2.
I am writing some insertion of data, as below.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionstring) 
db = client.somedb
x = { 'b' : 5}
db.mycollection.insert(x)
```

1. How can I make sure my insert to mongodb was securely(end to end encryption/ or some way third person cannot sniff while data transfer for insert) done?
2. For to do a securely insert, is there a setting required for MongoDB setup?

Comment: Define "secure".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen end to end encryption/ or some way third person cannot sniff while data transfer for insert is being done.

Comment: Look here for [how to configure mongodb for TLS/SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)